# Python paramiko push var on remote host

Tags: python, paramiko

some one know, how can i use variable to execute on remote host with paramiko?
For example i try to put multiple files and execute/make executable it.

```
SRCFILE='/root/test1.py'
DSTDIR="/tmp/"
dstf= 'runremote.py'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("chmod +x" + '' + DSTDIR + dstf)
```

This lines are only for example not the Script. 
My issue, i get nothing from stdout and the file are untouched.
if i run `stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("chmod +x /tmp/runremote.py")` get output on stdout and my file is changed.

Comment: Try `exec_command("chmod +x " + DSTDIR + dstf)`

Comment: THX! OK! Cool that is it, so easy!

Comment: THX! OK! Cool that is it,